# jQuery: if/else statement: it cant read the else statement it reads only first if

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have basic if-else statement. it cant read after if parts which are else if and else. İt only reads first if. this is my code. What might be the problem here.

```
if (screen.width < 992) {
alert('Less than 992');
 $("#res_img").toggleClass('col-lg-6 col-lg-5');
 $("#res_img_two").toggleClass('col-lg-6 col-lg-7');

 } else if (screen.width < 425) {

 alert('Less than 425');
 $("#res_img").toggleClass('col-5 col-12');
 $("#res_img_two").toggleClass('col-7 col-12');

 }
 else {
   console.log('success');
 }
```

Comment: If your screen width is less than 425, then it will be less than 992. So the second block will never be reached. If you need different behaviour based on whether the screen width is less than 425 or if it's between 425 and 992, then swap the positions of your `if` and `else if` sections so the more restrictive condition is checked first.

Comment: @MarkHanna why not provide it as an answer?

Comment: @Dropout only because I found the question a bit unclear so I wasn't sure if that answers it in its entirety.

Comment: @MarkHanna thanks for reply I appriacte it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, your code will run only once every page reload, be aware of that in testing.
Second of all, let's rewrite what you wrote in code in plainer "pseudo" instructions:

```
if width of the screen is less than 2 pixels {
    say 'Less than 2';
 } else if width of the screen is less than 1 pixel {
    say 'Less than 1';
 }
 else {
    say 'success';
 }
```

Maybe this way it is more clear, that every screen that is less than 1 will be always less than 2 pixels, so, really, there is no real way to separate those two cases, when you ask this way.
We can try to rearrange this question like this:

```
if width of the screen is less than 1 pixels {
    say 'Less than 1';
 } else if width of the screen is less than 2 pixel {
    say 'Less than 2';
 }
 else {
    say 'success';
 }
```

Then every screen that is less than 1 will be always less than 2 pixels, and if it is more than 1 but less than 2, then only the second statement will be true. But I think our intentions can be written more clearly as:

```
if width of the screen is less than 2 pixels and width of the screen is more than 1 {
    say 'Less than 2 but more than 1';
 } else if width of the screen is less than 1 pixel {
    say 'Less than 1';
 }
 else {
    say 'success';
 }
```

Comment: You don't need the third case, because if your second case's "less than 1 pixels" condition is met than its second "less than 2 pixels" condition won't be checked. Still, I agree it can certainly be clearer to be more explicit in conditions when you need to see if a value is between two points.

Comment: btw, it is an interesting question if there are OOP languages that will still run both branches. Should I edit to something more clear like

Comment: @Павел Пешеев thanks for your respond. I fixed it as you explained. I added this make my site responsive but you are saying it will run only once every page reload. İf thats the case, it is pointless to add these attributes I guess. Becasue when I reduce the screen size should I also refresh the page to see changes. Did I got it correctly? If so how can I prevent that to see changes immediately while I changing the screen size?

Comment: You should look up the [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) in JS and in particular resize the window event, but I suggest starting with simple mouse clicks, just to test. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0 this is also a really good talk to figure out what and how things happen on the web page, even if some things would be mystery for a while.

Comment: I'd also recommend learning about `@media` rules in CSS, because you don't need to use any JavaScript to make a site responsive: [@media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)